# Сумасшедшая цена

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, выбор-слов, значение-слов, прилагательные

Про какую цену можно так сказать? Высокую или низкую? Или и так и так?

Answer (score 3):

*Сумасшедшими* ценами неформально называют недоступно **высокие**, абсурдные с точки зрения говорящего. **Низкие** цены неформально называют *смешными*.

Answer (score 1):

В толковом словаре Дмитриева:
[сумасшедший](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dmitriev/5244/%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9), *прил., употр. часто*
**9.** Сумасшедшим называют то, что лишено здравого смысла.
*Сумасшедшая идея, мысль. | Сумасшедшие планы.*

В толковом словаре Ефремовой:
**сумасшедший**
3) *перен. разг.* Чрезвычайный, исключительный по величине, силе, степени 
проявления.

Цена — это денежное выражение ценности вещи, ее стоимость.

Сумасшедшая цена — это исключительная, нереально завышенная (эксклюзивная одежда, автомобили на заказ, раритетные драгоценности или произведения искусства, предметы коллекционирования...) или нереально низкая (глобальная распродажа [*Весь товар по 100 рублей!*], опт при ликвидации или банкротстве, скидка при срочности продажи [*Отдам за треть цены!*]) цена.

У каждого свой здравый смысл при оценке "сумасшедшести" цены: для кого-то сто евро — деньги, а кому-то и тысяча — мелочь.

*Сумасшедшие* [высокие] *цены на недвижимость в Крыму.*
*С 10 по 14 апреля во всех универмагах СТОКМАНН будут сумасшедше низкие цены на любимые бренды.*